# If $X\sim U(0,n)$, how can I show that $X-[X]\sim U(0,1)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

If $X\sim U(0,n) ; n \in \mathbb N$ ,  how can I show that the distribution of $Y =X-[X]$ is $U(0,1)$?

Any hint will also help me...

Comment: You should show your work/share your thoughts in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $Y=X-[X]$, and $0<y<1$ $P(Y<y)=P(0<X<y,1<X<1+y,\ldots n-1<X<n-1+y)=P(0<X<y)+P(1<X<1+y)+\ldots +P(n-1<X<n-1+y)=n\times y/n=y.$ Hence $Y\sim U(0,1).$

Comment: It probably would be helpful to use align so that the key step is better readable.